# Listview Error on longpress of item for deletion

Tags: java, android

[Visual Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrxLA.png)

[**EDITED WITH COMMENT FIX**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtmbe.png)

My listView is supposed to, on long tap, delete whatever you tap on. There is data in sharePreferences, so that shouldn't be the problem. So, what I am doing is I am taking data from noteSet, which gets it from myPref. Then, where the listView gets clicked, the notesSet deletes that note. Then, it reuploads the modified notesSet to sharedPreferences and then notesSet is added to notes, which is used by the listview.

I think this is the error code I am getting:

02-23 12:20:12.384 5211-5229/com.example.jackson.collegeplanner E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_OPERATION

02-23 12:20:28.461 550-710/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '17b2c24b com.example.jackson.collegeplanner/com.example.jackson.collegeplanner.Schedule (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

02-23 12:22:12.723 54-54/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 54: eglCreateSyncKHR(1299): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)

```
    myPref.edit().putStringSet("NN", notesSet).apply();

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Pop Up!")
                    .setMessage("Ready to delete this task?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            SharedPreferences myPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.jackson.collegeplanner", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            Set<String> notesSet = new HashSet<String>(myPref.getStringSet("NN", null));
                            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
                            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            notesSet.remove(i);
                            notes.clear();

                            notes.addAll(notesSet);

                            myPref.edit().putStringSet("NN", notesSet).apply();

                            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                            Log.i("TEST", "notesSet didn't return null!");

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();



            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is a snippet of code from my program for convienence. The rest of the program works, and app crashes only occur when I introduced this new code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: That logcat output isn't from your crash. You're looking for a big section that starts with `FATAL EXCEPTION`, likely all red. I would guess that you're getting an Exception from passing `getApplicationContext()` to `AlertDialog.Builder`. That needs to be an `Activity` `Context`. Change it to `YourActivity.this`, for example. Specifically, `Schedule.this`, if it's the same as in your previous question.

Comment: Thanks. I've been doing some lessons and I've been trying to deviate from the course, but they said to use getApplicationContext there. It now allows the popUp to appear, but now it crashes when I click the delete button. Ill upload a photo, but you've really done enough. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Acivity's context instead of `getApplicationContext()` . Do not use `getApplicationContext()` anywhere unless it meant to be use . Do it as below .

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActtivity.this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Pop Up!")
            .setMessage("Ready to delete this task?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.jackson.collegeplanner", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Set<String> notesSet = new HashSet<String>(myPref.getStringSet("NN", null));
                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                    notesSet.remove(i);
                    notes.clear();
                    notes.addAll(notesSet);
                    myPref.edit().putStringSet("NN", notesSet).apply();
                    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(YourActtivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    Log.i("TEST", "notesSet didn't return null!");
                }
            })
            .show();
```

Also Debug your code check and for returned values .